# Reading and writing String files with JSON in java

Tags: java, json, string, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I want to read a text file and process it's data.so for example the input file will look like :

```
john,judd,134
Kaufman,kim,345
```

then the program should parse and store these data in form of a JSON file so it will be organized for further processing.I'm using [JSON-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) for this task .and this is a prototype code I've written:

```
package com.company;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {


static JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
static String output;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    read("/Users/Sepehr/Desktop/JSONexample.txt");
    write("/Users/Sepehr/Desktop/JSONexampleout,txt");

}

public static String read(String filenameIn) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filenameIn));
    String s ;

    while ( (s = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null)

    {
        String[] stringsArr = s.split(",");


        jsonObject.put( "famname" , stringsArr[0] );
        jsonObject.put("name" , stringsArr[1]);
        jsonObject.put("id", stringsArr[2]);

        bufferedReader.close();


    }

    return output=jsonObject.toJSONString();


}


public static String write(String filenameOut) throws FileNotFoundException {

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(filenameOut);
    printWriter.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
    printWriter.close();

    String se = "yaaayyy :|";
    return se;

}



}
```

after running the program these are the exceptions I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:97)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:292)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
at com.company.Main.read(Main.java:30)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

what is wrong exactly ?

and how should make a better design for this program ?

Comment: On a side note, don't forget to fix the typo in the output file name extension (dot instead of comma) `write("/Users/Sepehr/Desktop/JSONexampleout.txt");` 

`JSONexampleout.txt` not `JSONexampleout,txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the BufferedReader in your loop

```
while ( (s = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null)

    {
        String[] stringsArr = s.split(",");


        jsonObject.put( "famname" , stringsArr[0] );
        jsonObject.put("name" , stringsArr[1]);
        jsonObject.put("id", stringsArr[2]);

        //*************
        bufferedReader.close(); // don't close the reader!
        //*************

    }
```

Comment: note that you should not simply delete the `close` statement, but move it so that it executes **after** the loop is finished

Comment: thank you @ControlAltDel can you give any advise about the overall design of this program I want to make?